# org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'orderId' for method of type String is not present

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot

I am trying to connect razorpay gateway with my react and I am using spring boot as backend but I am getting this(Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'paymentId' for method parameter type String is not present]) on the STS terminal.

**This is my Pay component
**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Pay = () => {
  const [orderId, setOrderId] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    createOrder();
  }, []);

  // Function to create a new order on the server
  const createOrder = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:8080/payment/createOrder"
      );
      console.log(response.data);
      setOrderId(response.data.id);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error creating order:", error);
    }
  };

  // Function to open Razorpay checkout
  const handlePayment = () => {
    const options = {
      key: "rzp_test_UqBICcJOEJD4nH",
      amount: 5000, // amount in paisa
      currency: "INR",
      order_id: orderId,
      name: "Your Company Name",
      description: "Payment for Premium Subscription",
      image: "",
      handler: async (response) => {
        try {
          const { razorpay_payment_id, razorpay_order_id, razorpay_signature } =
            response;
          console.log(razorpay_payment_id);
          console.log(razorpay_order_id);
          console.log(razorpay_signature);
          // Verify the payment on the server
          const verifyResponse = await axios.post(
            "http://localhost:8080/payment/verify",
            {
              orderId: razorpay_order_id,
              paymentId: razorpay_payment_id,
              signature: razorpay_signature,
            },
            {
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
              },
            }
          );

          if (verifyResponse.data) {
            // Payment successful, you can redirect or perform any action here
            axios.get("http://localhost:8080/payment/payment-success");
            alert("Payment successful");
            console.log("Payment successful");
          } else {
            // Payment failed
            axios.get("http://localhost:8080/payment/payment-failure");
            alert("Payment failed");
            console.log("Payment failed");
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error verifying payment:", error);
        }
      },
      prefill: {
        name: "User Name",
        email: "user@example.com",
        contact: "1234567890",
      },
      notes: {
        address: "Your Address",
      },
      theme: {
        color: "#528FF0",
      },
    };

    const razorpay = new window.Razorpay(options);
    razorpay.open();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Razorpay Payment Gateway</h1>
      <button onClick={handlePayment}>Pay Now</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Pay;
```

**this is my Payment controller
**

```
package com.tunehub.project.controller;


import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.tunehub.project.entities.Users;
import com.tunehub.project.services.UsersService;
import com.razorpay.Order;
import com.razorpay.RazorpayClient;
import com.razorpay.RazorpayException;
import com.razorpay.Utils;

import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSession;

//@CrossOrigin("*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/payment")
public class PaymentController {
    @Autowired
    UsersService service;

    @GetMapping("/pay")
    public String pay() {
        
        return "pay";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/payment-success")
    public String paymentSuccess(HttpSession session) {
        String mail =  (String) session.getAttribute("email");
        Users u = service.getUser(mail);
        u.setPremium(true);
        service.updateUser(u);
        return "customerHome";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/payment-failure")
    public String paymentFailure() {
        return "customerHome";
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("finally")
    @PostMapping("/createOrder")
    @ResponseBody
    public String createOrder() {

        int  amount  = 5000;
        Order order=null;
        try {
            RazorpayClient razorpay=new RazorpayClient("rzp_test_UqBICcJOEJD4nH", "J3vxuNudUteoWa9zX7UDoEmd");

            JSONObject orderRequest = new JSONObject();
            orderRequest.put("amount", amount*100); // amount in the smallest currency unit
            orderRequest.put("currency", "INR");
            orderRequest.put("receipt", "order_rcptid_11");

            order = razorpay.orders.create(orderRequest);

            

        } catch (RazorpayException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            return order.toString();
        }
    }   
    
    @PostMapping("/verify")
    @ResponseBody
    public boolean verifyPayment(@RequestParam(value = "orderId")  String orderId, @RequestParam("paymentId") String paymentId, @RequestParam("signature") String signature) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Received orderId: " + orderId);
            System.out.println("Received paymentId: " + paymentId);
            System.out.println("Received signature: " + signature);
            
            // Initialize Razorpay client with your API key and secret
            RazorpayClient razorpayClient = new RazorpayClient("rzp_test_UqBICcJOEJD4nH", "J3vxuNudUteoWa9zX7UDoEmd");
            // Create a signature verification data string
            String verificationData = orderId + "|" + paymentId;

            // Use Razorpay's utility function to verify the signature
            boolean isValidSignature = Utils.verifySignature(verificationData, signature, "J3vxuNudUteoWa9zX7UDoEmd");

            return isValidSignature;
        } catch (RazorpayException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

but I am getting "**POST http://localhost:8080/payment/verify 400 (Bad Request)**". I am successfully getting all the payments on the Razorpay account but I just want to verify if the user has done the payment or not in the verifyPayment() method.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are sending your data on the request body. @RequestParam expects a query param, something like:

```
http://localhost:8080/payment/verify?orderId=123&paymentId=123&signature=abc
```

The second parameter in axios.post sends that object as the request body, which your verifyPayment body is not expecting. You can either:

- Change the verifyPayment method to work with a [@RequestBody](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body) and
  create an object with orderId, paymentId and signature.
- On axios.post, send your data on the third parameter to [make them work as query parameters](https://www.kindacode.com/snippet/axios-passing-query-parameters-in-get-post-requests/). You can do this by adding "params" on the same object you are already filling the headers:

---

```
const verifyResponse = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:8080/payment/verify",
        {
            // Here you can add anything to the body request
        },
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          // Move your parameters here
          params: {
            orderId: razorpay_order_id,
            paymentId: razorpay_payment_id,
            signature: razorpay_signature,
          },
        }
      );
```